# The implicit conclusion results (Path Computations)

Tags: prolog

[image]I want to call this predicate when the result is displayed clearly, and not forcibly, through write.

```
    :- dynamic oil/2.

    oil(town1,3).
    oil(town2,9).
    oil(town3,2).
    oil(town4,4).
    oil(town5,9).
    oil(town6,2).
    oil(town7,4).

    % пример: qwerty('town5').

    qwerty(Tree, V, W, T):- 
        capacity(V),
        oil(Tree,W),
        T = [well]
        get_oil(V, W, Tree, 0, T).

    %get_oil(V, 0, Tree, Length, WellPath):- writeln(V), writeln(Length), writeln(WellPath).
    get_oil(V, 0, Tree, Length, WellPath).       
    get_oil(V, W, Tree, Length, WellPath):- 
        W<V,    
        V2 is V-W,
        get_oil(V2, 0, Tree, Length, WellPath). 

    get_oil(V, W, Tree, Length, WellPath):- 
        W>=V,
        W2 is W-V, 
        capacity(V2),
        way(Tree,L),
        NewLength is Length+L*2,
        get_oil(V2, W2, Tree, NewLength, [Tree|[well|WellPath]]).
```

Now it turns out:
    8 ?- qwerty('town5',H,D,P).
    H = 5,
    D = 9,
    P = [well].
    And I want to receive:
    H = 1,
    D = 38,
    P = [town5,well,well].

Comment: Why is this problem called the "The implicit conclusion results"? The screenshot is just the result from the first clause of get_oil/5, where you see true since V isn't bound. But I guess the problem is some path calculation.

Comment: In the screenshot it looks like you're calling get_oil/6, but `get_oil` is arity 5, so I'm confused.